# Проверка списка отозванных сертификатов

Tags: android, криптография, java

В `Android` можно каким-либо образом указать, что при использовании `SSL/TLS` нужно проверять списки отозванных сертификатов (`CRL`) или всё нужно реализовывать самостоятельно?

В `JavaSE` есть способ указать в `SSLContext` такую проверку.

```
PKIXBuilderParameters pkixParams = new PKIXBuilderParameters(truststore, new X509CertSelector());
    CollectionCertStoreParameters params = new CollectionCertStoreParameters(crls);
    CertStore store = CertStore.getInstance("Collection", params);
    pkixParams.addCertStore(store);
    pkixParams.setRevocationEnabled(true);
    ManagerFactoryParameters trustParams =
            new CertPathTrustManagerParameters(pkixParams);     
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    tmf.init(trustParams);

    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    kmf.init(keystore, keystorePassword.toCharArray());

    this.sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance(algorithm);
    this.sslcontext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
```

Но в `Android` нет нужного криптопровайдера для этого.

Answer (score 2):

Можно, просто параметр **setRevocationEnabled** находится в классе [PKIXParameters](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/cert/PKIXParameters.html), а не в [PKIXBuilderParameters](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/cert/PKIXBuilderParameters.html). Необходимо создать и использовать экземпляр этого класса и его передавать в качестве параметра в конструктор *CertPathTrustManagerParameters*